# How can I check when integer is incremented beyond a multiple of a number?

Tags: objective-c

I've made a game where the player is awarded 3 or 5 points depending on the type of enemy they take out. I want to increase the maximum number of enemies spawned each time the player's score reaches a multiple of 50.

This is what I've got so far (located within the method where the score is adjusted):

```
if (self.score % 50 == 0)
        {
            if (self.maxEnemiesA <= 20)
            {
                self.maxEnemiesA++;
            }
        }
```

The code detects when the score hits a multiple of 50, but since the score is a combination of two different increments, the odds are it will skip over that target.

e.g. If the score is 148 then incremented by 5 it will skip over 150 and become 153.

Rather than check if the score is a multiple of 50, how can I detect the moment the score *passes* a multiple of 50?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simpler:

```
// Let BASE_ENEMIES be the starting number of enemies, when the score is
// less than 50.
self.maxEnemiesA = MIN(20, BASE_ENEMIES + self.score / 50);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I would rather register points at which you increased the number. Set the current score in a variable and check if it has increased by more than 50

```
if (self.score >= previousScore + 50) 
{

      previousScore = self.score;
      if (self.maxEnemiesA <= 20)
      {
            self.maxEnemiesA++;
      }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the score before and after any increments you make.

```
NSInteger oldStep = self.score / 50;
// Code that increments self.score as needed
NSInteger newStep = self.score / 50;
if (newStep > oldStep) {
    // The score has increased into a new multiple of 50
}
```

Example: If the score is currently 148, `oldStep` will be 2. If you then increase the score to 153, `newStep` will be 3.